Filter pictures by face offline like in Google Photos
I have about 10,000 photos in a folder I copied from WhatsApp media. I want to filter the photos based on faces. I don't want to upload these photos anywhere. Without uploading, I want to filter these photos offline.
Is there any way to filter and Android-preferred?

Related on Reddit: Looking for a photo app that lets you group faces (without uploading to cloud), face recognition gallery app
